# Access Custom Class Variables in a ViewModel through binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

What I want to do is to be able to access an object's properties through a bound textblock that is found in a viewModel class. So say I want to access the OrderID of the Orders class in a bound textblock that is stored in a viewModel class. 
What I have for that is:

```xml
<textblock text="{Binding Path=Order.OrderID}"/>
```

This is connected to the order's orderID as when I change the OrderID in the ViewModel class the change is reflected in the textblock. The problem occurs when I try to load the OrderID from another class.

The Other class:

```cs
public class ModifyOrder
{
   private ViewModel boundData;
   public ModifyOrder()
   {
      boundData = new ViewModel();
   }

   public void ChangeOrderID()
   {
      boundData.Order.OrderID = 10;
   }
}
```

The changes here don't get transfered to the static _Order in the ViewModel class.

This is the viewModel class:

```cs
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private Orders _Order;
   public Orders Order
   {
      get { return _Order; }
      set 
      { 
         if (_Order != value)
         {
            _Order = value;
         }
      }
   }

   public ViewModel()
   {
      Order = new Orders();
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

I have the ViewModel class loaded into the UI's DataContext and my other bound variables in the ViewModel class work fine but for some reason either the bound textblock isn't accessing the Order.OrderID (Which I don't think is the problem since I can modify the Order.OrderID in the ViewModel class and the changes are reflected) OR the class that's modifying my Order isn't able to modify the OrderID.

I've already tried to load a new Order class with the new OrderID and then try to load the ViewModel's _Order with the ModifyOrder's new Order but that hasn't worked out either.

This is the Orders class:

```cs
public class Orders : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private int _OrderID;
   public int OrderID 
   { 
      get { return _OrderID; } 
      set 
      {
         if(_OrderID != value)
         {
            _OrderID = Value
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(OrderID));
         }
      } 
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

```xml
<Page x:Class="SPWally.FunctionalPages.LookupOrders"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SPWally.FunctionalPages"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="LookupOrders">

    <Grid Background="AliceBlue">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" Text="Search For Order" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,335,0" Text="OrderID: " />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="300" Margin="0,0,20,0" Text="{Binding Path=OrderIDSearch, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="40" Height="20" Margin="10,0,0,0" Content="Find" Click="Find_Click" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="50" Height="20" Margin="70,0,0,0" Content="Refund" Click="Refund_Click" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,100,0" Text="OrderID:"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,100,0" Text="Customer:"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,100,0" Text="Product:"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,100,0" Text="Branch:"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,100,0" Text="Sales Price:"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,100,0" Text="Quantity:"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Margin="30,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Order.OrderID, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Margin="30,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Order.Customer.FullName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Margin="30,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Order.Product.ProductName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Margin="30,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Order.Branch.BranchName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Margin="30,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Order.SalesPrice, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Margin="30,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Order.Stocks, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

        <Button Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="60" Height="25" Content="Cancel" Command="{x:Static NavigationCommands.BrowseBack}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Keep in mind that I've literally learned everything I know about data binding in the last 48 hours so bear with me here.

Any kind of help at all is very much appreciated. Thank!

Comment: You're not invoking `OnPropertyChanged` in your `Order` setter. You also need to do it for the properties in your `Orders` class such as `OrderID` etc.

Comment: @MarkFeldman How do you mean invoke ```OnPropertyChanged``` for the OrderID? It's in a different class so I can't invoke it there. Do I have to make a copy of the properties in the ViewModel class too in order to do this?

Comment: Correct. Change notification does not happen "auto-magically", WPF controls specifically look for INotifyPropertyChanged events to update themselves. This means you either have to add INPC to your underlying data objects (generally frowned upon, but can be done either manually or [automatically at compile time](http://www.shenchauhan.com/blog/2018/6/18/fody-inotifypropertychanged-the-easy-way)) or you have to design it into your view model layer and handle updates between that layer and your model layer using whatever method is most convenient for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in Orders class.
You need to Invoke OnPropertyChanged() inside all setters.

Comment: I've just changed it right now both in my code and in the question but the problem is still there. Does the ```PropertyChanged``` Event handler have to be connected to the one in the **ViewModel** class too? If so how would I go about that?

Comment: Can you post the XAML which uses the VM ?
"_PropertyChanged Event handler have to be connected to the one in the ViewModel class too_?" No

Comment: Okay, I've added it to the question.

Comment: Is the ViewModel object set as datacontext of the view ?
What is the purpose of ModifyOrder class ? You can do those things in the viewmodel

Comment: Yes I Set the ViewModel to the view's datacontext and the ModifyOrder class is the intermediary class that holds the mysql commands to lead the order and other classes

Answer (score 0):

Where your view model is getting instantiated ? I guess since you are recreating your viewmodel instance in ModifyOrder class 
`boundData = new ViewModel();`
binding is lost and may be because of that its not showing up .

Answer (score 0):

...Yeah, so. It was the

```cs
public ViewModel()
{
   Order = new Order();
}
```

that was wiping clean the `private static Orders _Order` in the ViewModel class every time it was instantiated so I changed it to

```cs
public ViewModel()
{
   if (_Order == null)
   {
      Order = new Order();
   }
}
```

and that fixed the problem...

Thanks to everyone that helped me out with this! I learned a lot from you all!

I'm going to go cry myself to sleep now <3